# AnjularJS get value of textboxes after button press

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I set the values of textboxes via a ajax request in my controller like this :

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: url}).success(function(data) {
                $scope.valzz = data;
                $scope.company = $scope.valzz[0].Company;   

            });
```

Then in my html :

```
<label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
            <span class="input-label">Company :</span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Company" value="" ng-model="company">
          </label>

<button class="button button-positive" style="margin-top:10px;" ng-click="saveChanges()">
  Save Changes
</button>
```

This correctly puts the company name in the company textbox. But when make a change to that textbox and press the save button, the new value of the textbox isnt showing - it still gets the original. This is the button click in the controller :

```
$scope.saveChanges=function(){

            alert($scope.company);

    };
```

Why is `$scope.company` not the new value of the textbox? am i doing something wrong? (sorry if basic i am new to angular)

Comment: Try passing company to the saveChanges function

Comment: It's a form with 30 or so fields, do i really need to pass them all?

Comment: nvm haha could you add more code so I can take a look?

Comment: It should work since it's doubly binded i.e. models and views

Comment: @sebenalern Thats all there is really mate i just took the other 29 variables and textboxes out haha

Comment: It's just sticking with the old value it got from the get request

Answer (score 2):

Try removing `value=""`

HTML:

```
<label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span class="input-label">Company :</span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Company" ng-model="company">
</label>

<button class="button button-positive" style="margin-top:10px;" ng-click="saveChanges()">
  Save Changes
</button>
```

In corresponding CONTROLLER:

```
$scope.saveChanges = function() {
    alert($scope.company); 
};
```

Comment: Still not the new value :(

Comment: Can you have a basic fiddle so that I can debug it there?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a watcher for that model.

```
$scope.$watch('company', function(company) {
  console.log(company);
}
```

Or in your template, you can interpolate the value:

```
{{company}}
```

And then you can see it changing on the html page, because angular make a watcher for it behind the scene

Answer (score 0):

Needed to put this.company not $scope

Answer (score 0):

Please define $scope.company before $http call

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http){
  $scope.company = null; // <--
  $http({method: 'GET', url: url}).success(function(data) {
    $scope.valzz = data;
    $scope.company = $scope.valzz[0].Company;

  });
}
```

Because, once the partials has rendered, it gets only the defined properties in `$scope`. After that if any property is added inside $scope it needs to call the `$apply`.

Hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that you have $scope working properly, and that you have initialized the controller in your app, as well as linked to the proper controller file. Please compare your code to what I have here, as this is working properly.

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src ="controller.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="testController">
<form>
    <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
                <span class="input-label">Company :</span>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Company" ng-model="company">
              </label>

    <button class="button button-positive" style="margin-top:10px;" ng-click="saveChanges()">
      Save Changes
    </button>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('testController', [ '$scope', function ($scope){

            $scope.saveChanges=function(){
                alert($scope.company);
            };

        }]);

})();
```

Edit: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ezjnkphy/13/)